# Waiting to get boolean is true

Tags: java, android, okhttp

this code below is a for loop on a web service how to wait until boolean is true before every loop

check the comment in code

```
    for (i=0;i<contactsString.length-1;i++){
        Phone phone=new Phone();
        phone.phone=contactsString[i];
        check=false;
        WebService.getInstance().getApi().checkNumber(phone).enqueue(new Callback<MainResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MainResponse> call, Response<MainResponse> response) {

                availableUsers++;
                check=true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MainResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        //--- here how to wait untill check is true then continue the loop

    }
```

Comment: where are you assigning check=true in code.

Comment: inside onResponse

Comment: at the place of loop use recursive function.....that will work fine in this condition

Comment: The `check` variable in `onResponse` is local to that method.

Comment: why are defining two check variable two times?

Comment: You don't really want to wait there until check is true. What if the request fails?

Comment: I want every time in the for loop wait for response which is waiting for boolean to be true when it's true the second time it is set to false and then waiting again to be true and so on

Comment: I'll add more code when fail later this is what I want when it is success

Comment: call a method in `onResponse` to trigger the next check. That way your loop is not necessary. This will be sort of a recursive call that will call itself until you reach the end of the list

Comment: You could make your API wait for a true response instead of killing your device with an infinite  request loop

Comment: well this helps a lot and I will accept this answer tyvm

Comment: fixing my web service now idk why it stopped when I but it in a separate function

Comment: @RealDEV think about sending all the phone number in one shots and getting the response and do the whatever you want

Comment: yes tried that and I know it is supposed to be like this but I still can't handle the web service smoothly and receive an array of values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to wait untill check is true then continue the loop

use a recursive function

delare and initialize `availableUsers=0` as a field. To start the loop, call `checkNumber()`

```
   private int availableUsers=0;

   public void checkNumber() {
      this.checkNumber(0);
   }
   private void checkNumber(final int i){
        if(contactsString==null || i>=contactsString.length){
           return;
        }
        Phone phone=new Phone();
        phone.phone=contactsString[i];
        WebService.getInstance().getApi().checkNumber(phone).enqueue(new Callback<MainResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MainResponse> call, Response<MainResponse> response) {


                availableUsers++;                    
                checkNumber(i+1);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MainResponse> call, Throwable t) {  
               checkNumber(i+1);

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I get array out of bound when I set it to contactsString.length

Comment: need a little more help guys :D
I can send and receive a string value with retrofit how to send an array and receive another array and what is it's json form the sent and received form a simple example would help me understand if possible

Comment: @Darish if you set the method private, you need to create a public one like `public void checkNumber() {this.checkNumber(0);` to hide the recursive solution. That prevent someone to call `checkNumber(100);` But yes, this is correct. Do you understand why now ? That the most important

Comment: Perfect, the few last changes were probably not necessary but this will be much safer like this.